# Next.js Route API - Getting Body Values

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am trying out the new Route API's in Next v13.2, but cannot seem to figure out how to get the body values in a POST request.

On the client side, I am calling the API something like this:

```
      const response = await fetch("/api/bot", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ prompt: "Testing" }),
      });
```

I then created a file in the app directory called route.js

I created the function for the POST request and tried fetching the values from the request object in numerous ways, with no luck.

Something like:

```
export async function POST(request) {
  console.log("Request", request.body.prompt);
  return new Response({ response: prompt });
}
```

I tried fetching the body values from the request objects, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Drove me crazy. I found the answer here in the NextJS repo: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/46483

Answer (score 5):

With **Next.js 13.4** by sending the POST request like this:

```js
const response = await fetch("/api/bot", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ prompt: "Testing" }),
      });
```

you can make the following to extract the body data:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function POST(req) {
  const body = await req.json()
  return NextResponse.json({prompt: body.prompt})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the following:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

...

return NextResponse.json({ response: prompt });
```

Source : https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/response

[from doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOEjO.png)